# Derivative of a simple function

Tags: calculus

I started to learn little about the definition of derivative, and I come across the following function. What is the derivative of the following function
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x-a,\ \ \text{if}\ x\geq a\\
x,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{if}\ x<a
\end{cases}.
$$
The function is obviously not continuous (at $x=a$) and hence I believe that the derivative is $1$ for any $x\neq a$ and not defined at $x=a$. If I'm right, how can I modify the function such that it's derivative will be defined at $x=a$?

Thank you.

Comment: You're correct that the derivative is not defined at $a$ (**if** $a\neq 0$). But you need to take a look again at what the derivative is when it is defined; are you sure that the derivative of the function $f(x)=x$ can be made to be *any real number $a$ that you choose*?

Comment: The derivative is not $a$; is that a typo?  In order to be differentiable, first it must be continuous.  What values of $a$ make the function continuous at $a$?  You can take left-hand and right-hand limits to find out.

Comment: Yes, it is a typo (fixed). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to make this function differentiable at $a$ by modifying it only at $a$.  Because the left- and right- limits do not agree, the function will not be continuous at $a$, no matter what you assign as its value at $a$. And not being continuous, it can't be differentiable.

But you can make the function differentiable everywhere by modifying it in a small neighborhood of $a$ - as small as you wish. In a picture, it looks like this: from

[image: bad]

you get

[image: good]

The method I used here is called [mollification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier). To be precise, the second function is defined as

$$g(x)=\int_{-0.1}^{0.1} f(x-t) \,(10-100|t|)\,dt$$

which isn't the best mollification possible but is simple to write, and good enough to make the function once differentiable.